# Astronauts visit a spot in space, to gain valuable knowledge but always dies in 24 hours returning earth and not speaking anything

Tags: story-identification

The novel is about cargo cult, a primitive civilizations conducting various acts in order to return with goods from an advanced civilization, like someone entering a blackhole and returning with a 4k tv in 1900s

- Astronauts are sent to a space to this place to gain unknown
  knowledge/ technology, but the astronauts returning Earth are either
  dead or die in 24 hours. The astronauts won't speak of their
  experience or are too frightened of their experience
- The protagonist is some sort of a social worker/psychologist/ therapist, his duty is to
  relieve the emotions of those astronauts returning Earth and try to
  get them to speak up about their experience.
- Toward the end, the book mentions some astronauts returning to Earth
  with a cure for cancer. One astronaut dies in the space shuttle
  scrawling words around the wall of the shuttle.

The novel is related to lovecraftian horror/ cosmic horror.

Comment: Is this one novel or are you trying to ID multiple books?

Comment: @Valorum one novel

Comment: Some elements remind me of Pohl's Heechee series but I don't seem to remember the protagonist is a social worker.

Comment: @ZabZonk i have a faint memory of  the book, maybe some sort of a psychologist/ therapist that deals with the emotional elements of astronauts returning earth from the spot

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is very much like *[Hinterlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinterlands_(short_story))*, a short story by William Gibson.  The copy I have was published in [Burning Chrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burning_Chrome_(short_story_collection)).

> Astronauts are sent to a space to this place to gain unknown
>   knowledge/ technology, but the astronauts returning Earth are either
>   dead or die in 24 hours. The astronauts won't speak of their
>   experience or are too frightened of their experience

There is a point between Earth and Mars where ships with solo astronauts – but only some of them – disappear.  Those that disappear may reappear later, and often bearing something intimating contact with a more advanced race.  Those that reappear are also insane and suicidal.

> The protagonist is some sort of a social worker/psychologist/
>   therapist, his duty is to relieve the emotions of those astronauts
>   returning Earth and try to get them to speak up about their
>   experience.

The protagonist is one of those who failed to disappear, and who now meets the returnees and tries to nurture them to live.

> Toward the end, the book mentions some astronauts returning to Earth
>   with a cure for cancer. One astronaut dies in the space shuttle
>   scrawling words around the wall of the shuttle.

I believe the first returnee, Olga Tovyevski, returned with a seashell of non-terrestrial origin.  A later returnee, "returned with a twelve-centimeter ring of magnetically coded steel locked in his cold hand… that ring was the Rosetta stone for cancer."

The returnee that the protagonist greets has scrawled on her ship: "Then I saw the insane frieze of ballpoint scratchings, crabbed symbols, thousands of tiny crooked oblongs locking and overlapping.  Thumb-smudged, pathetic, it covered most of the rear bulkhead."

Comment: It is that novell

Answer (score 0):

Not a novel, but a short story: [Hinterlands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinterlands_(short_story)) by William Gibson.

Comment: Thanks so much!!!!

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is the correct answer?

Comment: @Valorum: it matches all mentioned plot points perfectly.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt You need to spell it out. _We_ get why it fits, but does a passer by user? Does the OP?